# Does H2 + Cl2 produce 2HCl a redox reaction

Tags: redox

Is $\ce{H2 + Cl2}$ produces $\ce{2HCl}$ a redox reaction?

Answer (score 4):

Anything that involves change of oxidation states of reactants in the products or exchange of electrons can be considered a redox reaction.

Here, $\ce{H2}$ (oxidation state = 0) changes to $\ce{H+}$ (oxidation state = +1) and $\ce{Cl2}$ (oxidation state = 0) changes to $\ce{Cl-}$ (oxidation state = -1)

So, $\ce{H2}$ has been oxidised and $\ce{Cl2}$ has been reduced, making this a redox reaction.

Comment: While I agree about the formal change of oxidation states let us be clear; Hydrogen Chloride is not an ionic substance, it is covalently bonded

Comment: My mistake. Of course, I shouldn't have called them ions. I'll amend that in a second.